# Flask-Migrate multidb foreign key to different bind can not find target table

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am trying to use Flask-Migrate with multiple databases using the flask-sqlalchemy `__binds__` feature. When trying to establish a foreign key between two different binds, `flask db migrate` fails with the error `sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError`, i.e. can not find the table to establish the foreign key.

I am using Postgres databases with bind keys `db1` and `db2`. Note that this error does not occur if the foreign key is to a table on the same bind (database).

Here is a sample app that demonstrates the problem:

#### app/models.py

```py
from app import db

class People(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db1'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Cats(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    people_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('people.id'))
    dogs_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dogs.id'))


class Dogs(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

#### app/**init**.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app,db)

from app import models
```

A `config.py` file is used to set the sqlalchemy binds from environment variables:

#### config.py

```py
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
        'db1': os.environ.get('DATABASE_1_URL'),
        'db2': os.environ.get('DATABASE_2_URL')}
```

In this example, the foreign key in the `Cats` table to the `Dogs` table is established with no errors:

`dogs_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dogs.id'))`

However doing the same thing to the `People` table,

`people_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('people.id'))`
results in the error when running `flask db migrate`:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'cats.people_id' could not find table 'people' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

Threads, such as [this one](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/172) indicate the foreign key should be established by including the schema name, or bind key:

```py
people_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('db1.people.id'))
```

however, this results in the same error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'cats.people_id' could not find table 'db1.people' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

Any suggestions for this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should note, to make this run there is also a `main.py` file with `from app import app`, and a `.flaskenv` file to set `FLASK_APP=main.py`.

Comment: Are foreign keys across databases supported by Postgres? How does that work?

Comment: Ugg I think you are correct, I didn't even consider it. If you want to write it as an answer I'll mark it. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot define foreign keys across databases. If you can move all these tables into a single database, maybe putting them in different schemas, then you'll be fine.

Comment: It seems like the ideal solution is to collocate data on the same database while using FK constraints, but I'd think the ORM would be able to provide a slower version of the _functionality_.  It may not be as ACID-compliant (isolated/durable/consistent), but it would provide a means to create a relationship map between models using joins, even if they're not strict ISO FKs.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `schema` and set the foreignkey with it.

```
class People(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db1'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'db1'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)


class Cats(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'db2'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    people_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('db1.people.id'))
    dogs_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('db2.dogs.id'))


class Dogs(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'db2'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work. As mentioned in the other answer, you can't set foreign keys across different databases even though the logic would make sense in Flask. Once you try to run that as a migration script, it will not run.

Comment: In my case, I have a <branch> table in default DATABASE_URI and other <branch> table in sqlalchemy_binds.
When I define db.ForeignKey it always choose branch in default DATABASE_URI and failed because branch struct is difference. And your solution is work. Thanks.

Comment: The question was regarding PostgreSQL.  In Postgres, schemas are more like permissioned-namespace behind the same auth.  They're easy to cross-map. The issue is the tables are in two completely separate databases, which are a little more difficult to link, and different servers adds another layer.